# Jenkins build history by branch view

Tags: linux, jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson, continuous-deployment

I've played around with Circleci and one thing that I really like is that they allow you to select a branch of a project and then view all the builds that've occurred in that branch. I'd love to implement this on our Jenkins server. Is there a configuration or plugin that does that?

Here's a quick mock-up of what I'm talking about:

```
MyProject: 
  - master
  - branch1
     -> build1
     -> build2
     -> build3 
     -> ...
  - branch2
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can accomplish most of what you want with Jenkins.  The [Git Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) does allow you to have one build that will build all (or some) branches of a repository (or multiple repositories). You can just leave the Branch Specifier field blank in the Git Plugin configuration to build all branches or you can specify a pattern like "*/feature/**" which would build all branches matching the pattern.

Then install the [Build Name Setter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Name+Setter+Plugin) and then in your build configuration under Build Environment check the box next to "Set Build Name" and use `#${BUILD_NUMBER}: ${GIT_REVISION,length=8} (${GIT_BRANCH})` as your build name.

This will result in your build history looking something like this:

```
#5: 2743f83d (master)
#4: d0b4eada (feature/featureB)
#3: 777e92c7 (feature/featureA)
#2: 15b6d92b (master)
#1: 6b625f7f (master)
```

It's not hierarchical like in your mock-up but pretty close to it.

Comment: We are also attempting an organized build history view by branch, so I was very excited to see this post. This is definitely an acceptable workaround, @Kyle. Thank you for posting! Unfortunately, there is an issue with the token macro that makes the GIT_variables unrecognizable. I tried various versions of the and always get:
_Unrecognized macro 'GIT_BRANCH' in '${BUILD_NUMBER}: (${GIT_BRANCH})'_
This is an [old issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-13347), but looks like it's still relevant. I'm going to try with a couple other plugins, and I'll let you know where I get.

Comment: Work around is to call the variables from the environment. For example, instead of `${GIT_BRANCH}`, you would use `(${ENV,var="GIT_BRANCH"})`. Unfortunately, this won't let you use the parameters to shorten length, so you might not want to use GIT_REVISION.

Comment: Nice @Kyle, this looks good. I've moved on to CircleCI since asking this question, but what you've described is pretty close to what I was looking to do.

Answer (score -2):

Jenkins works differently. You have to create one job per one branch. My team combines project's name with branch's name, so job's name will be like `my_project-master` and `my_project-branch-1`.

Comment: Ouch, that's painful, considering we have dozens, if not hundreds of branches for our various projects. Thanks for confirming that for me though.

Comment: You want hundreds of branches to be built by your ci engine?

Comment: This is not true.  The Git Plugin for Jenkins can build all branches of a repository. See my answer for a solution to the question.

Comment: @Kyle OP doesn't state anything about Git so I assume he wants to setup a CI that works with any source control systems. With that assumption, my answer works with TFS, Git, etc. It's more flexible.

Comment: Since he mentioned CircleCI, which relies on GitHub, I think it's pretty clear he is looking for a solution for Git. Regardless of that, you say that in Jenkins "you have to create one job per branch" which is inaccurate. You only have to do that for non-git repositories.